# Metasmoke: Web dashboard for SmokeDetector

Tags: app, flags

[metasmoke](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/metasmoke) is a web dashboard for [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/). You can see it here:

#### https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com

It's a fun project, and I need a Stack Apps post so I can have write access to the API.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-spam-automatically/